# Is there any NuGet API to create a Package from a Visual Studio Extension project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget-package, visual-studio-extensions, envdte

I am looking a api that helps us to **create NuGet package** from a vsix project.
I found apis used for installation of Package like - `NuGet.VisualStudio`.

Please let me know if there is any similar api for creation and publish of a package as well.
I need to create package with selective files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope these can help you:

- Use [Nuget/PackageBuilder](https://apisof.net/catalog/NuGet.PackageBuilder.PopulateFiles(String,IEnumerable%3CManifestFile%3E)) to create a packge. The sample: [Build Package](https://github.com/NuGetArchive/NuGet.VisualStudioExtension/blob/dev/Tools/NuGet/GenerateTestPackages/Program.cs).
- Use [NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types/PackageUpdateResource](https://apisof.net/catalog/NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageUpdateResource) to upload the project. The sample: [Upload Package](https://gist.github.com/evillegas92/b10bbb8b5ed9657579e6c2d13609e261).

Comment: Thank you @PerryQian-MSFT  Your solution was all in one for my queries.